# Can Doxygen recognize std::shared_ptr or std::map

Tags: c++, doxygen

Is it possible to teach Doxygen to recognize a member of type `std::shared_ptr<T>` as an aggregation? I think it does it for normal pointers, although I have added `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT=YES`.

The question also extends to `std::unique_ptr` which should be a composition, and I think `std::map<K,V>`, `std::vector<V>` etc could be documented as composition with multiplicity 1...N, although I am pretty sure I don't want this in all cases.

If this is not possible with Doxygen, I would be interested in alternative documentation systems for C++.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.8.14, Doxygen doesn't add `std::shared_ptr<T>` to the internal list of std classes when `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT` is on.

But it's relatively easy to add it by modifying Doxygen sources. In `src/doxygen.cpp` there's a global variable `g_stlinfo` that holds definitions of standard classes. Also, `addSTLClasses()` function in the same class has a branch for smart pointer classes.

Refer to [this changeset](https://github.com/Sleepyowl/doxygen/commit/6c380ba91ae41c6d5c409a5163119318932ae2a3?diff=unified) for minimal change to enable shared_ptr support.

Unfortunately, I cannot answer the rest of your question yet.